# Magento 1.7 + Apache + 2GB RAM super slow with new theme

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, optimization, memory

We have a low traffic Magento 1.7 on a 2GB RAM VPS, and when we changed to a new theme (a SNS theme) the CPU to 100% usage almost all the time, even with very little traffic, and the site is almost unusable.

On a development server we had no problem, and when we rollback to the previous theme (quite outdated) there is no problem, but with this theme/server it's very bad.

We changed the  part to only 15 servers/maxclients because with the default (8-50) we had downtime when the traffic was up. That change, suggested by [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761239/apache-server-reached-maxclients-setting-consider-raising-the-maxclients-settin) was good because we don't have downtime anymore, but the server still is very slow (like 10sec-40sec each call slow).

I know 2GB of RAM is very low, but that's the server we got and we can't do anything about it. We can't upgrade Magento either :(

Would you give us any suggestion?

[Here is a gist with httpd conf files and htaccess](https://gist.github.com/altuzar/62ad51bf125987ca823bc27f8086ec58)

### Versions

Magento version: 1.7.0.2
Apache version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
PHP version: 5.3.26 (cli) 
MySql version: 5.5.31-log

### System Info

Processor   : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4332 HE
CPU Cores   : 2
Frequency   : 3000.112 MHz
Memory      : 1998 MB
Swap        : 1953 MB
OS      : CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
Arch        : x86_64 (64 Bit)
Kernel      : 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: anything in error logs or strace the process??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, bought themes are very often put together without following Magento's best practices or built with flexibility in mind more than performance.   We've often decided to just theme a site from scratch for efficiency because it's less time than dealing with someone else's mess.

Make sure you have a full-page cache on the site.  It makes a world of difference.

If the theme is causing you these problems, is dropping it in favor of a better performing theme an option?   If not, then it really goes down to reviewing your new theme block by block for inefficiencies.

It makes it more difficult to test if your dev environment isn't experiencing the same issues.

What's the difference with the dev server setup as compared to production other than less traffic?

Comment: Thanks. Creating a new theme or choosing a new one is not possible right now, I'm afraid. The test server is quite similar to the production server for specs/versions, I'm afraid. We developed with local Mamp servers without issues, so it was quite a surprise when the site was that slow on production. I'll make some test and report back.

Comment: Enabling and configuring the cache really made a huge difference. Now the speed is still not fast but usable, so thank you!